# Count should be zero if more than one null is available in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column which can have a null value in it.
I need to write a query which will return 0 if column have more than one null value in it.

Below is the table structure:

```
ID | FNAME     | LNAME    | Country | ReportTo 
---+-----------+----------+---------+----------
1  | Davolio   | Nancy    | USA     | null 
2  | Fuller    | Andrew   | USA     | null 
3  | Leverling | Janet    | USA     | 1
4  | Peacock   | Margaret | USA     | 2 
5  | Callahan  | Laura    | USA     | 2
```

I need `0` as a count if `Reportsto` column contains null value in it.

Comment: You need to show the table structure, sample data and expected output.

Comment: @GirishMahida Below what? And is this count part of some existing SQL?

Comment: Below is the table structure.
ID  FNAME    LNAME   Country    ReportTo
1  Davolio            Nancy     USA          null
2  Fuller       Andrew     USA          null
3  Leverling  Janet     USA     1
4  Peacock   Margaret     USA            2
5 | Callahan | Laura     USA            2

I need 0 as a count if Reportsto column contain null value in it. Also I am allowed to do it only by modifying the where clause

Comment: @GirishMahida Please edit it into the question, in such a format that it is easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, FNAME, LNAME, Country,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE Reportsto END AS Reportsto
FROM
    t
```

Or (You can use below statement like `WHERE 0 = (SELECT ...)`)

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM
    t
```

Comment: @GirishMahida And you didn't think that's something you should have included in the question?

Comment: @GirishMahida In `Where` clause you can just filter the results but you said you want to return a 0 value if count of Null values are more than one!